# Image among flex items within grid cell causes horizontal overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a simple grid design, with three rows and a single column. In one of the rows, I use flexbox to display 3 items horizontally. I'm testing all this with various window sizes and in responsive mode in both FF and Chrome.

When all three flex items are `div`s containing text, everything behaves as expected. When I replace one item with an `img`, I get something strange : I can't reduce the width of the window under a certain threshold without causing horizontal overflow (bottom scrollbar appearing). It looks like it wants to keep a certain aspect ratio.

I've made a codepen here : https://codepen.io/mavromatika/pen/rNOVLdE

Try commenting out the `img` and uncommenting `<div>works</div>`, and changing the window width.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.contenant-presentation {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(0, 1fr) 10fr minmax(0, 1fr);
}

.premiere-ligne {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

.troisieme-ligne {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}

.troisieme-ligne div {
  /* height: 100%;*/
}

.troisieme-ligne img {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenant-presentation">
  <div class="premiere-ligne"></div>
  <div class="deuxième-ligne"></div>
  <div class="troisieme-ligne">
    <div>This</div>
    <div>works</div>
    <!--<img src="https://etc.usf.edu/clipart/65200/65255/65255_dipper_lg.gif">-->
    <div>fine</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: After doing a few experiments, it turns out that setting `grid-template-column` to `100%` instead of `auto` seems to solve my problem. I wish someone could explain the reason to me, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the bottom scrollbar, try adding this:

```
.contenant-presentation{

  overflow-x: hidden;

 }
```